# Pygsheets update_cells() not working

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

I am trying to update a range of 3 cells horizontally using pygsheets but I am having some issues

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Art\Desktop\Python\Plain\General_testing.py", line 12, in <module>
    wks.update_cells('I{0}:K{0}'.format(rows),[output['Name'], output['Age'], output['State']])
  File "C:\Users\Art\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\worksheet.py", line 431, in update_cells
    self.client.sh_update_range(self.spreadsheet.id, body, self.spreadsheet.batch_mode, parse=parse)
  File "C:\Users\Art\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py", line 352, in sh_update_range
    self._execute_request(spreadsheet_id, final_request, batch)
  File "C:\Users\Art\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py", line 418, in _execute_request
    response = request.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Art\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Art\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 842, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1P2FvtuOLWZGgVIp-D9ROeBqexXQt1eNv8tSxZdwGrlw/values/Sheet1%21I19%3AK19?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&alt=json returned "Invalid value at 'data.values[0]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "Joe"
Invalid value at 'data.values[1]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "19"
Invalid value at 'data.values[2]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "NY"">
```

Simplified version of my code that produces the same error:

```
import pygsheets

gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='secret.json')
sh = gc.open('TestSheet')
wks = sh.sheet1

row = 1
output = {}
output['Name'] = 'Joe'
output['Age'] = '19'
output['State'] = 'NY'
wks.update_cells('I{0}:K{0}'.format(row),[output['Name'], output['Age'], output['State']])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update cells take a 2D matrix (list of list) as input for values not a list

```
wks.update_cells('I{0}:K{0}'.format(row),[[output['Name'], output['Age'], output['State']] ] )
```

see the docs [here](http://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worksheet.html#pygsheets.Worksheet.update_cells)

Comment: hey, please post a new question with complete stack-trace. and steps to reproduce.